# How to distinguish transitive and intransitive verbs?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

I want any key or shortcut to distinguish between transitive and intransitive verbs.Wren and Martin says that when a verb is used transitively the action passes over.But what ai am inable to understand is how does it pass over ?

For example in a sentence "I looked down from my window." Is the action passing over ?

"Time changes all things." Is it transitive ?

Or if there's any other way or book recommended do inform me.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what Wren and Martin said (and in which book or webpage)? By itself, "_the action passes over_" is a nebulous concept at best. Have you searched online for other resources that explain transitive/intransitive verbs and give examples?

Comment: What do you mean by: passing over. transitive verbs are often action verbs

Answer (score 1):

*Transitivity* is not a semantic concept, but a syntactic one: any book which tries to define it in semantic terms is unhelpful. (It is also language-dependent).

There is not much about the semantics which will tell you that, in English, *eat* is usually transitive, but *dine* is always intransitive.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to find the "direct object" or the object that receives the action of the transitive verb. If you can find a direct object then the verb is transitive; if you can not find a direct object then the verb is intransitive (in- meaning there is no object to receive the action from the verb). 
http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/transitiveverb.htm
 http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm

Comment: But Allerton, in The Handbook of English Linguistics_eds Aarts and McMahon, claims that post-verb noun groups such as those appearing in

'The piano resembled a pianola.' / 

...

 / 'The piano had a stool.' / 

'The piano seemed an antique.'

should not be considered objects but are 'best regarded as belonging to a slightly different category'. Though 'Many people like chocolate' uses a transitive non-action verb. Assuming Allerton's model is tenable, how does one identify a true direct object?